# MariaDB Engine for Cache

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an InnoDB table in my system that caches the products in my virtual store, every 5 minutes this table is emptied and re-created. But every 30 days it corrupts at least 1 time, what is the best search engine to use in the cache table in mariadb 10.1, remembering that every 5 minutes I clear all records and recry and have high volume reading.

```
CREATE TABLE `cache_produtos` (
  .....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: What's the point of a cache table if you empty and recreate it every 5 minutes? What exactly did you achieve with that? `InnoDB` is sufficient. You're just using the database wrong, completely. Create your table, increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` - it tells MySQL how much RAM it's allowed to allocate for faster I/O. Get a server with sufficient RAM to run your store. Create your cache table and **update it** correctly, don't drop and recreate it or flush its contents. That's pointless.

Comment: Look into query cache for MariaDB: Might solve your issue in a transparent fashion